# Quotation character becomes question mark

Tags: character-encoding

On my local server, a certain page content displays this character : <kbd>“</kbd> (quotation mark). But exactly the same page on my online server displays : <kbd>?</kbd> (question mark). How can I fix that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark characters displaying within text, why is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241015/question-mark-characters-displaying-within-text-why-is-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that either the server is sending the encoding or you have a meta tag in the `<head>` section as described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html (or both).