# Encoding Problems using JSON and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
"nombre": "Jesús Ramírez",
"edad": "25 Años",
"imagen":"file.jpg"
}
```

I get data from json using jquery function $.getJSON, but I have a problem when I show data in my html document. I do this:

JAVASCRIPT

```
   $.getJSON(file.json, function(data) {

        var name= data.nombre;
        document.getElementById("student_name").innerHTML=name;

        var age= data.edad;
        document.getElementById("student_age").innerHTML=age;


        var photo= data.imagen;
        document.getElementById("student_img");
        student_img.src=photo;


  });
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="student_name"></div>
<div id="student_age"></div>
<img id="student_img"></img>
```

But data is showed like this:

- Jes�s Ram�rez
- 25 A�os

I'm using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and I tried:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV= "Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

but they don´t work.

Anyone can help me? what can I do to solve this??

Comment: Might find some useful info in here  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241015/question-mark-characters-displaying-within-text-why-is-this***

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> should work, did you put it inside head tag?

Comment: The server may be producing the JSON in the wrong character encoding (something other than UTF-8).

Comment: but I'm working on local files, im not using a server to load data, what can i do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To show spanish characters you can use the corresponding html special characters.
I suggest to write a function to replace the characters with the right html chars.

Here is a list. [HTML Codes for Spanish](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-sp.htm)

### Update

You can use this function to convert.

```
function HTMLEncode(str){
  var i = str.length,
      aRet = [];

  while (i--) {
    var iC = str[i].charCodeAt();
    if (iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC>90 && iC<97)) {
      aRet[i] = '&#'+iC+';';
    } else {
      aRet[i] = str[i];
    }
   }
  return aRet.join('');    
}
```

Comment: This should definitely not be necessary.

Comment: I tried to replace it using javascript functions but it doesn't work.
My json file was saved by a java application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the service that sends you the JSON information, I highly recommend that you URL-encode it before sending to the webpage.

If your service is written in PHP, for example, you could do this:

> echo urlencode($your_json_string);

Comment: I'm not using php or a server to load my data.
All my application is for local working. First, a java application builds the json file, then I use jquery to parse my json file and finally show the data in a HTML page

Answer (score 0):

You could set the content type of your AJAX request before, even though the use of [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) is not recommended.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});
```

Another idea would be using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)instead of [`$.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {
       var name= data.nombre;
       document.getElementById("student_name").innerHTML=name;

       var age= data.edad;
       document.getElementById("student_age").innerHTML=age;


       var photo= data.imagen;
       document.getElementById("student_img");
       student_img.src=photo;
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stekhn/09krhLt5/1/) to prove that it is working.

Comment: I'm not using php or a server to load my data. All my application is for local working. First, a java application builds the json file, then I use jquery to parse my json file and finally show the data in a HTML page, im not using ajax. only javascript

Comment: As the Fiddle shows, this works as well with local data. Jquery's .getJson() is nothing but a simplified, preconfigured .ajax() call. And since the configuration doesn't fit your use case, you will encounter encoding problems. The right way to solve this is setting the correct encoding when getting the data – not fixing the data afterwards with some obscure parsing.

Comment: As for the JSFiddle: You have to press "Run" first to see results.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. But, I can't see the JSFiddle, link is down.