# question marks instead of arab letters

Tags: amp-html

All the english pages work well. Only Arabic pages show the problem.

All pages contain `<meta charset="utf-8">`

[image: screen shoot]

> ���á �ä ���Ç ��Á ��ä ����ä ���á �å �Ç ���ã ���Ê �ì �����ã ����ì ����Ê ����å ����Á ����É ��Ç ���ä �ì ���ì �����Ç ��á ���ß ��ä ����ä ���á �å ��ß �Ï ����Ì ����É ����É ����á ���É ����Þ ����Ç ��Ñ ��á ���ì ������Ç ��å ��Á ����Ç .

When I am entering from the browser there is no problem but the problem is when enter from Google search

example:http://www.dreams-image.com/amp.php?t=71657

Answer (score 2):

Your document is not using a UTF-8 character encoding. Your server is responding with a windows-1256 encoding, but UTF-8 is required.

Comment: That's right, my database is not UTF-8
But it is difficult to convert all database to UTF-8 . 
Is there a solution without converting the database? . 
and Why there is no problem when entering from the browser and not from Google search? .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Gregable's answer, none of the encoding settings in your bullet list will actually modify your output in any way; all they do is tell the browser what encoding to assume when interpreting what you send. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445327/5832311), you're getting those �s because you're telling the browser that what you're sending is UTF-8, but it's really  windows-1256. Additional reference which might help: [Question mark characters displaying within text, why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241015/question-mark-characters-displaying-within-text-why-is-this)